# How to only add rows to table which don't exist MSaccess

Tags: excel, ms-access

My first post/question here, I have searched and tried many options but nothing seems to fit exactly what I need. 
I am building an `Access DB` to manage scheduling work and assigning employees to that work.  The Scheduled work comes from an `Excel Sheet` that I've imported into `Access`.  I don't have control over how the data comes to me or the format.

So I have a table 'tblTempP6' with the scheduled work for the year. Several columns determine a unique entry.

I have another table '`shtP6DataEast`' has an index which is the primary key. the two tables are the same except `shtP6DataEast` entries has and index. so i can access specific entries and assign employees etc..

Each time i get a new sheet to import the existing scheduled work is still in the sheet and i dont want duplicate entries with different ids.

I have tried Left Joins but have had issues because i need to use 4 columns as the unique identifier...

Any thought?

Thanks

forgive my NOOB Question

```
SELECT tblTempP6.[Project #], tblTempP6.[Work Order #], tblTempP6.[Project Name], tblTempP6.[Activity Name], tblTempP6.[TOA #], tblTempP6.Start, tblTempP6.Finish, tblTempP6.[Budgeted Labor Units], tblTempP6.[S/S - SUBSTATION], tblTempP6.iCircuit, tblTempP6.isStreet, tblTempP6.[Test Group Work Type], tblTempP6.Comments, tblTempP6.[Resource IDs]

FROM tblTempP6 

LEFT JOIN shtP6DataEast ON tblTempP6.[Project Name] = shtP6DataEast.[Project Name]

WHERE (((shtP6DataEast.[Project Name]) Is Null));
```

Comment: MSAccess. Sorry

Comment: I am trying to build a statement that returns the rows from the tempdata that are not in the schedule table already. so i can add them to the schedule table

Comment: Show us the code/sql you currently use to put rows from `shtTempData` into `tblScheduleEntries` and then we can tell you how to change it to do this.

Comment: I Updated the initial question with the statement... thanks

Comment: The table names do not match your question.  Which is supposed to be `shtTempData ` and which is `tblScheduleEntries `?

Comment: you do know the join `ON tblTempP6.[Project Name] = shtP6DataEast.[Project Name]` could have multiple `and` conditions for the other 3 needed join fields right?

Comment: Yes and i tried that, ended up returning no rows. I'll try again, make sure i didnt miss something silly but that is exactly my question

Comment: you may need to trim (eliminate leading and trailing spaces) the results maybe some data has spaces at the end. Focus in on one record from both tables and make certain that the data for each column is EXACTLY the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I will try to answer this generally, using `tmp` as the name of the table with the freshly imported and possibly duplicated data, and `dat` as the name of the table with the previously imported, permanent data.

There's a bunch of ways to do it, here's how to do it with LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM  tmp
LEFT JOIN dat  ON  tmp.KeyCol1 = dat.KeyCol1
               AND tmp.KeyCol2 = dat.KeyCol2
               AND tmp.KeyCol3 = dat.KeyCol3
               AND tmp.KeyCol4 = dat.KeyCol4
WHERE dat.IDcol IS NULL
```

You do the left join against the existing data, and then exclude all rows that actually matched to that table.

Comment: Thanks! i will implement and see

Comment: So in the `where` statement, do i not need to include the other fields that could be null?... nevermind..... stupid question, I misunderstood what the where column was actually doing...  IF i understand correctly now, the ID column from the permanent data would be returned null for the new data.

Comment: @G.Bassaragh That's right, the `IS NULL` only needs to check one column from the reference table that could not otherwise be NULL.  This can be any column that is defined as `NOT NULL`, but typically you use the ID/autonumber column if there is one, or the leading primary key column.